# Scilab 2023.0.0 in Windows: console quickly closes

Tags: windows, scilab

Installed Scilab 2023.0.0, when trying to run it, the console opens and immediately closes.

I have installed: VC_redist.x64.exe

PC configuration:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  C8N26AV
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3201 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Hewlett-Packard L01 v02.75, 04/05/2018
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
Platform Role   Desktop

```
Z:\>cd C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\bin\
Z:\>c:
C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\bin>Scilex.exe
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
Error: Could not parse file C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml
at line     4 of function scilabQuit Undefined variable: with_module
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
Error: Could not parse file C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73
 @author Dassault Syst?�mes
Error: Could not parse file C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml
```

Comment: Does the previous version (6.1.1) work on your computer ?

Comment: Can you try to launch the command line executable of Scilab (open a cmd then type something like `C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\bin\Scilex.exe`) and tell me the eventual output ?

Comment: C:\>C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\bin\Scilex.exe
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Just cd to the correct folder where the binaries of Scilab are then `Scilex.exe`

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\bin>Scilex.exe
file:///C:/Program%20Files/scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml:6: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xA8 0x6D 0x65 0x73 Error: Could not parse file C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0/etc/modules.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick workaround (until the new release), you can edit (e.g. with notepad) the following file

```
C:\Program Files\scilab-2023.0.0\etc\modules.xml
```

Delete line #6

```
 @author Dassault Systèmes
```

or retype the `è` by making sure that the character will be UTF8 encoded. Scilab should start normally.